# Como imprimir um JSON array?

Tags: javascript, json, array

```
var listaNomeProjeto =
    [{
        "nomeProjeto": "NomeProjeto1",
        "subProjeto": [
                "Sub Projeto1",
                "Sub Projeto2",
                "Sub Projeto3",
                "Sub Projeto4",
                "Sub Projeto5",
                "Sub Projeto6",
                "Sub Projeto7"
            ]
    },{
        "nomeProjeto": "NomeProjeto2",
        "subProjeto": [
            "Sub Projeto1",
            "Sub Projeto2",
            "Sub Projeto3",
            "Sub Projeto4"
        ]
    }];
```

Tentando imprimir com laço de repetição:
- No `$(this).val()` é recebido o valor de um select box.

```
    for( var i = 0; i< listaNomeProjeto.length; i++){
        if(listaNomeProjeto[i].nomeProjeto === $(this).val()){
            console.log(listaNomeProjeto[i].subProjeto[0]);

        }
    }
```

Eu faço uma busca no `nomeProjeto`, se eu achar o nome eu tenho que printar todo o conteúdo dentro do `subProjeto`. Eu devo fazer mais um loop para percorrer a array que está dentro do `subProjeto`? Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou sugerir uma solucão diferente, sem usar loops. Primeiro filtre pelo que você está procurando com o método **filter**:

```
listaFiltrada = listaNomeProjeto.filter(function(e) {
    return e.nomeProjeto === 'NomeProjeto2'
});
```

Essa lista contém apenas os projetos que você procura. Dentro da funcão você define os critérios para filtrar os resultados. Agora vamos transformar a lista, para obter a informação que você quer, com o método **map**:

```
subProjs = listaFiltrada.map(function(e) { return e.subProjeto; });
```

Para exibir a lista de subProjetos, **forEach**:

```
subProjs.forEach(function(e){ console.log(e); });
```

Sei que em javascript não fica bonito, mas se quiser você pode fazer tudo encadeado:

```
listaNomeProjeto
    .filter(function(e) { return e.nomeProjeto === 'NomeProjeto2' })
    .map(function(e) { return e.subProjeto; })
    .forEach(function(e){ console.log(e); });
```

Acho bem mais legível do que usar loops :)